# Move through a list of selenium webdriver objects when switching pages

Tags: jquery, python, selenium, web-scraping

I'm having a bit of trouble trying to put together the logic of having selenium go through a list of elements such as an unordered list, click a link that moves to another page and then move back to the original page proceeding with the next item in the list.
At first I was having errors with the elements being stale but was able to find with some looking that when the browser destroys the elements on the current page, they be come stale. Thus, I tried to remedy this by the following:

```
list3 = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id='treeContainer']//a[starts-with(@id, 's')]")
tempList3 = {}
for entry in list3:
    tempList3[entry.get_attribute("id")] = entry.text
    surveyNum = entry.get_attribute("id")
    print(entry.text, entry.tag_name)
    subList3 = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("#listContainer > ul > *")
    print("sublist", len(subList3))
    tempMem = {}
    for each in subList3:
        print(each.get_attribute("id"), each.text)
        tempMem[each.get_attribute("id")] = each.text
        reportNum = each.get_attribute("id")
        execute_click(driver, "#listContainer > ul a")
        element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
            lambda s: s.execute_script("return jQuery.active == 0"))
        if element:
            element = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(
            EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, "Export to CSV")))
            element.click()
        element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
            lambda s: s.execute_script("return jQuery.active == 0"))
        if element:
            csvRadio = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#exportValuesLabelsCSV3.radio")
            csvRadio.click()
        else:
            continue
        csvDownload = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(
            "#butExportToCSV > table > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(1) > div > button")
        csvDownload.click()
        element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
           EC.text_to_be_present_in_element((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#progress_csv'),
                                                  "Export completed! Please click here if nothing happens"))
        driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='emptySel']/a").click()
        subList3.clear()
        subList3 = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("#listContainer > ul > *")
        for items in subList3:
            print("subList3", items.text)
            if reportNum in tempMem:
                if tempMem.get(reportNum) in items.text:
                    subList3.remove(items)
                    print("Item removed, items left:", len(subList3))
                else:
                    continue
            continue
        else:
            continue
    tempMem.clear()
    list3.clear()
    list3 = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id='treeContainer']//a[starts-with(@id, 's')]")
    for listed in list3:
        print("list3", listed.text)
        if surveyNum in tempList3:
            if tempList3.get(surveyNum) in listed.text:
                list3.remove(listed)
            else:
                continue
        else:
            continue
    continue
tempList3.clear()
```

After running it I don't get any errors, however it seems that it does not loop... what have I overlooked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your overall code is difficult for me to follow without full context. That said, given your initial description, I would use css paths and `nth-child()`'s:

Lets say you wanted to find every link on Hacker New's main page, and then one-by-one click each link, hitting the back button in-between link clicks.

Hacker New's HTML looks something like this (as of May 2016):

```
<tbody>
      <tr class="athing">
            <td align="right" valign="top" class="title”>…</td>
            <td valign="top" class="votelinks”>…</td>
            <td class="title">
                  <span class="deadmark"></span>
                  <a href="https://github.com/BYVoid/Batsh">A language …</a>
                  <span class="sitebit comhead”>…</span>
            </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>…</tr>
      <tr class="spacer" style="height:5px"></tr>
      <tr class="athing">
            <td align="right" valign="top" class="title”>…</td>
            <td valign="top" class="votelinks”>…</td>
            <td class="title">
                  <span class="deadmark"></span>
                  <a href="https://chrome.googleblog.com/2016/05/the-google-play-store-coming-to.html">Play Store…</a>
                  <span class="sitebit comhead”>…</span>
            </td>
      </tr>
      …
</tbody>
```

Example code to find the anchor elements and click them one by one:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get("https://news.ycombinator.com/")

try:
    # The path to the links you want
    base_css_path = "tr.athing td.title > a"

    # Find and get a count for the number of links you will be clicking
    # Note the plural 'elements'
    num_elems = len(driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(base_css_path))

    # CSS path for finding individual elements
    ind_css_path = "tbody tr:nth-child({0}) td.title > a"

    # Starting with an index of 1, we want every 3rd tr child
    # Looking at Hacker News' structure, we know there are 3 total tr elements
    # associated with each tr we actually want, so we must multiply our total
    # element count by 3, and then use a step size of 3
    for index in range(1, num_elems * 3, 3):
        # Use the direct css path to acquire the specific element and click it
        driver.find_element_by_css_selector(ind_css_path.format(index)).click()

        # Redirect happens
        # Do whatever you need to do here

        # Return to the previous page
        driver.back()
finally:
    driver.quit()
```

Comment: This is definitely the right approach to this problem. Thank you for answering!